# How can I run system commands in C/C++ using `execl()`, passing the function arguments only as a command line, not as an executable file?

Tags: c++, c, linux, exec, execl

I would like to execute this command in a C/C++ program: `stat -c "%F %A %n" *filename goes here*`
The filename is stored in the `main` function's `argv[1]`.

I tried it as `execl("/bin/stat", "stat", "-c", "\"%F %A %n\"", "file", NULL);`

How should the `execl()` command look like to achieve the result?

Comment: Yes, of course i did, and I tried slicing the command into different parameters, but it either gives no output or writes `stat` not found.

Comment: I can't even run it using `system()` function.

Comment: @churill please refrain from the comments or answers which advise people to "google it".  Most of the time people come to these question/answer sites because a google search directed them here.

Comment: @grovkin I find that is important to know. If I know that someone searched the docs and tried something before asking it is much easier to help him. Unfortunately many people ask questions without doing some research first.
Now it is also clear what he tried. I did now mean to sound rude, sorry.

Comment: @BalogSzilárd Thanks for showing what you already tried! Do you intend to insert the filename from `argv[1]` to where you have the parameter `"file"`? Maybe you can do `execl("/bin/stat", "stat", "-c", "\"%F %A %n\"", argv[1], NULL);`.

Comment: Just executing `stat` like that is pretty pointless unless you're also capturing the output of the command... is that what you need help with?

Comment: @churill Yeah, that's what I would like to achieve.  But it doesn't give any output.

Comment: @Shawn Yes, I thought it would be displayed in the terminal.

Comment: Look into `popen()`.

Comment: I found my problem. The `stat` command is located in `/usr/bin` instead of `/bin`.

Comment: As @grovkin pointed out, most people come here in search of answers to their question. So please put your solution in an answer and mark it. It will be much easier to find.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your command should look like this:

```
int res = execl("/bin/stat", "stat", "-c", "\"%F %A %n\"", argv[1], NULL);
if (res == -1) {
   perror("/bin/stat");
   exit(1);
}
```

Then the perror would show you:

```
/bin/stat: No such file or directory
```

and you would realize that stat is in /usr/bin or that using execlp would have been a good idea.

Comment: Okay, so I was basically skipping on error checking, right?

Comment: You didn't see the error because you didn't check for it. The actual error was the wrong path in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I found my problem. The `stat` command is located in `/usr/bin` instead of `/bin`.